# Can i use jquery to manipulate css to change background image with base64 string

Tags: jquery, css

Here's the problem. i've a base64 image string which is dynamically retrieved from database via ajax.

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAvsAAAJECAYAAACIHevuAAAgAElEQVR4nO3d
```

after retrieving the string i want to set it as the background image of a div

```
<div id="dragBox"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you write the image file in some folder and return the path to that file via ajax? I think that would solve the case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try:

```
$('#dragBox').css('background-image', 'url(' + base64_string + ')');
```

basically, you just put the base64 inside `url()`.

more information:["Data URI scheme" Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: But yours is the js solution asked for.

Comment: This is exactly what i need.
But somehow it doesn't work on FF. but it works on my chrome.

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me in FF. you should make sure it is proper base64 with correct mime types. Also, I didn't know before, but the code should be wrapped in single quotes. So "url('"+base64_string+"')" should work, but it seems to work just fine for me both ways. Also, I'm not sure if it is related, but try Ctrl + F5 for FF. It _may_ be a cache issue...

Comment: Wouldn't `document.getElementById('dragBox').style.backgroundImage = ('url(' + base_64_string + ')');` do exactly the same thing without jQuery. I don't see the advantage here.

Comment: Yes it would, and I would normally advocate against using jQuery. However, the question specifically asked for it, and I hate the type of answers that assume there is not a reason for asking to do something a certain way, whether it just be for bad practice or sheer curiosity.

Comment: it didnt worked in ff for me too, but the trick was to add `"` double quotes inside the `url("...")` brackets

Answer (score 2):

You can simply place your image data directly into the `url` parameter of the `background` property in CSS.

```
#dragBox {
background: url(data:image/png;base64,iv[...]);
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uyrjs/