# Multiple base64 background-image through Ajax callback

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, callback

I have an Ajax call (callback with loop) through with I get multiple images in base64.

Who can i insert these images in background during Ajax callback "done".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to do this [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896192/can-i-use-jquery-to-manipulate-css-to-change-background-image-with-base64-string), by using [JQuery .css() Method](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=css):

JQuery:

```
$('#divID').css("background-image",'url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBE....==)');
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divID">
    Your div content
</div>
```

**Update:** Adding multiple backgrounds to a single HTML Element via JQuery you can do something like this (2 base64 examples, you can add more):

```
$('#divID').css("background-image",'url(data:image/gif;base64,R.....AAOw==), url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM..H09wdGltaXplZCBi==)');
```

You can add multiple `url()` with base64 string separated by comma `,` as `url(data:image/gif;base64..), url(data:image/gif;base64..), url(data:image/gif;base64..)`. But don't forget to write some `CSS` properties for your div(s):

```
#divID {
    width: 500px; // any width you like
    height: 250px; // any height you like
    background-position: center bottom, left top; // position you like
    background-repeat: no-repeat; // it is important if you don't want to see repetition of backgrounds 
}
```

> Note: Please avoid to use/make duplicate IDs for your divs, if you really wants to effect multiple divs then use Class for it and use `$('.divsClass')` then.

Comment: Thanks it's what i found, but i want to put multiple images(in base64) in background, not just one. How shall we do it ?

Comment: @MedMatrix please check my update and if it help you, don't forget to mark as correct :)